# getting 404 when sending post with body to web-api

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, http-post

A simple request, managed to do so before and thought I already went over all options:
Trying to post a simple request to a web-api controller.
**Managed to do so from the postman**, apply *enableCors*, **when sending body as null and no httpHeaders as options - managed to reach the controller REST method.**
BUT- when trying to send the body-receiving 404 and cors error (don't think that it is the correct error message).
See my code (may have typos-wrote it free hand, not copy+paste):

my controller :

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Data"]
public class DataController :ApiController
{

    [Route("Get")]
    public Object Get()//this is working
    {
        //do something 
    }
    
    [Route("Update")]
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post ([FromBody] DataObject data)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, true);
    }
}
```

DataModel:

```
public class DataObject
{
    [JsonProperty("Prop1")]
    public int Prop1 {get; set;}
    
    [JsonProperty("Prop2")]
    public string Prop2 {get; set;}
    
    
    public DataObject(){}
}
```

Client(angular):
client data model and calling function:

```
export class ClientDataObject
{
    public prpt1 :number;
    public prpt2:string;
    co structor(pr1:number, pr2 :string)
    {
        this.prpt1 =pr1;
        this.prpt2 =pr2;
    }
}

PostSomeData(property1:number, property2: string)
{
    const httpOptions =
    {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-type''Application/json'})
    }
    
    let data: ClientDataObject=
    {
        Prop1:1,
        Prop2: "test"
    }
    
    let data2: ClientDataObject =new ClientDataObject(1,"test");
    
    //All the options I tried:

    //This is working - null as body and no options     
    return this.httpClient.post<any>(<baseHref of the controller> + "Update", null/*,httpOptions*/);



    return this.httpClient.post<any>(<baseHref of the controller> + "Update", data,httpOptions);
    
    return this.httpClient.post<any>(<baseHref of the controller> + "Update", data); //without as httpOptions options

    return this.httpClient.post<any>(<baseHref of the controller> + "Update", 
    {
        'Prop1':1,
        'Prop2': "test"
    },httpOptions);
    
    return this.httpClient.post<any>(<baseHref of the controller> + "Update", JSON.stringfy(data),httpOptions);
    
    return this.httpClient.post<any>(<baseHref of the controller> + "Update", data2,httpOptions);
    
    
    return this.httpClient.post<any>(<baseHref of the controller> + "Update", data2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out-It was actually a CORS problem -I thought I enabled the CORS, but it turns out that not fully.
There are several ways\places\scopes to enable CORS. I was doing it in the **WebApiConfig.cs** file, in the Register method:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
   config.EnableCors();
   .......
}
```

BUT this wasn't enough - the EnableCors has overloads, and I needed to use it with an **EnableCorsAttribute** object, which is configured according to my preferences (origins, headers and methods.
So, this is what I needed to add (this can be done also in the web.config file, but not in both places):

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
   var corsAttribute = new EnableCorsAttribute("*","*","*");
   config.EnableCors(corsAttribute);
   .......
}
```